# Proving Expected Value Formula for Discrete Random Variable Involving Infinite Series

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I am currently trying to prove the following formula. Let Y be a discrete random variable that assigns positive probabilities to only positive integers. Show that:

$$
E(Y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty }P(Y \geq k)
$$
where k is a positive integer.

My initial foray into this involved abstracting it into two series, with the inner series having y go from k to infinity, and the outer series going from k = 1 to infinity, as so:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{y=k}^{\infty}P(Y=y)
$$

I am unsure what to do next. I had discussed this with a professor but his explanation remained confusing to me. I am still confused as to
what the integer k represents. Any help and insight would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a next step, you can swap the summations. Your double summation is over pairs $(k,y)$ with $y \ge k$, which we can also obtain as
$$
\sum_{y=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^y \mathbb{P}(Y=y).
$$
Note that the summand does not depend on $k$, so we simply get
$$
\sum_{y=1}^\infty y \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y=y),
$$
which, because $Y$ only takes positive integer values is by definition equal to $\mathbb{E}[Y]$.

Comment: Ah, I see now. Your point about the pairs with y >= k finally made the proof clear to me. Thank you so much!